# Prove the inequality $m(x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \Vert x \Vert >r)\leq \frac{1+r^2}{r^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\Vert x\Vert^2}{1+\Vert x \Vert^2}m(dx)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

When I read the lecture notes about the Levy process, I get stuck in proving the inequality:

$m(x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \Vert x \Vert >r)\leq \frac{1+r^2}{r^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\Vert x\Vert^2}{1+\Vert x \Vert^2}m(dx),$

where m is a Borel measure.

I try to：
$m(x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \Vert x \Vert >r)=\int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \Vert x \Vert >r\}}m(dx)\leq \int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \frac{\Vert x\Vert}{1+\Vert x \Vert}>r\}}m(dx),$
but how to get the inequality?

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @uniquesolution I forget how to get the inequlaity. Is it easy to get it?

Comment: @Shaun Hey! It is not my exercise and it appears in a lecture note about Levy process. Here is the Lecture

Comment: @Shaun http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/Levy.pdf

Comment: Your questions should come with context regardless of where they came from.

Comment: @Shaun in P3 the indentity (4).

Comment: @Shaun I just show that it is not my homework but I read lecture note let me be stuck in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(u)=\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$ is a strictly increasing function for positive $u$. Therefore:
$$
m(x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \| x \|> r)= m\left(x\in\mathbb R^d: \frac{\Vert x\Vert^2}{1+\Vert x \Vert^2}>\frac{r^2}{1+r^2}\right).
$$
Apply Markov's inequality to get your result.